# Reordering vertical tabs

Tags: forms

Is it possible to reorder vertical tabs in the node edit page?  There are certain buried tabs that I am constantly needing to switch to, and it would make my life much easier (and that of my users!) if I could change the order to put the frequently used tab on top.

***Note regarding similar questions***:
I realize something similar [has been asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/56771/7984), but he asked specifically about doing it by *weight*, and I'd be happy with *any* method of reordering them, in case there are other ways.  And no one answered his question, which leads me to hope there is some other way to do it.  If there's no way to do this at all, then I'll either delete this question--if that's the general consensus of the community--or accept the answer that it's not possible, as long as it is convincing and no one disputes it.

Comment: I have given an answer to the question you mentioned http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/56771/7984 hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines of the other mentioned question and its comments and answer, I've been able to pull out these useful bits of information.

1. You can do this with
   [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)
2. You can find the correct FORM_ID by looking at the HTML source of the form you're working with.  It's given inside the  tag.   *Apparently* you need to replace the hyphens with underscores.
3. The code might include *something* like this:

```
function hook_form_sublanding_page_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['promotion_settings'] = array(
    // something goes here....
  );
}
```

The code is *very* incomplete and quite possibly incorrect.  Perhaps someone will complete/correct it.